# iPhone app in simulator works on one mac but not another mac

Tags: iphone, xcode, simulator

I hired 2 developers to work on an App and both developers have no problem loading the App in the Simulator.  However, on my iMac, it won't load the App at all in Simulator and only gives me the icon screen of the App.

I got paranoid and did a clean install of OS X and upgraded to 10.6.6
I even erased the hard drive completely before install
running Xcode 3.2.5
developers are also running Xcode 3.2.5 iOS SDK 4.2

I did Clean Targets
I did reset in the Simulator

Maybe something in the Xcode Preference Settings?

Has this happen to anyone before?

--

Answer (score 1):

Have you see them load the app?

Here are few suggestions/options:

- Try to load a test app and just
  see if it is actually your computer.
  http://www.tuaw.com/2009/04/27/iphone-dev-101-the-hello-world-app/
- Have the developers use TeamViewer
  (http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx)
  to load the app in your phone for
  you.
- You have to sign your app through
  apple dev store, are you on the list
  of developers that can open/edit the app?

Comment: Teamviewer is a great idea.  They loaded the app just fine on their Mac.  It turns out the problem was related to the provisional profiles and distribution keys.